# Gridlines are not zooming in Scatter plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

When I am zooming(i.e. default magnifying using allowsUserInteraction of plot space) gridlines are remains at same place. I want to make it zoom or it should be in coordination of tick mark. 

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=433) in the release version 1.0 it has been fixed in the development version, to use this version you will have to clone the mercurial repository by doing the following:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/
```

To install mercurial you should be able to download the installer [here](http://mercurial.berkwood.com).